# How to get the pose and 4x4 matrix from the log file and save them as a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, numpy, matrix

i have a large log file that contains poses and 4x4 matrices, i want to split each matrix to 3x3 rotation matrix and 3x1 translation matrix and each matrix is specified by pose_number(just first number on top of each matrix is pose_number) and save them into a JSON file like this format ( {"pose_0": {"rotation": [[1.00000000 , 0.00000000 , 0.00000000 ], [-0.00000000 , 1.00000000  , -0.00000000 ], [ 0.00000000 , -0.00000000 , 1.00000000 ]], "translation": [ 0.00000000 ,0.00000000  , 0.00000000 ]}, "pose_1": {"rotation": ...... ) )
,. also i show all of them in the picture[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibEre.jpg).
since i am new in this field i do not know how to do that, i would be grateful if someone could help me with that or give me some similar example. thanks [These is my log sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibEre.jpg)
this is a sample of the log file :

```
0 0 1
1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
-0.00000000 1.00000000 -0.00000000 0.00000000
0.00000000 -0.00000000 1.00000000 0.00000000
0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000
1 1 2
0.99987256 -0.00294761 -0.01569025 -0.00016514
0.00261951 0.99977833 -0.02089080 0.00523247
0.01574835 0.02084704 0.99965864 -0.00371881
0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000
2 2 3
0.99973679 -0.00740811 -0.02171352 0.00091496
0.00681182 0.99960112 -0.02740798 0.01052933
0.02190790 0.02725285 0.99938848 -0.00518150
0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000
```

and the output for the first matrix should be like this:

```
{"pose_0": {"rotation": [[1.00000000 , 0.00000000 , 0.00000000 ], [-0.00000000 , 1.00000000  , -0.00000000 ], [ 0.00000000 , -0.00000000 , 1.00000000 ]], "translation": [ 0.00000000 ,0.00000000  , 0.00000000 ]},
```

Comment: This has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689242/convert-log-file-into-json-file-using-python

Comment: Post the code you've written so far. It should include a sample log of a few items and the desired result as a JSON string. "log file" is a very general term and its impossible to guess what such a 4x4 matrix log even looks like.

Comment: @tdelaney actually i have uploaded a sample of the log file you can find it at the end of the question, also i have written the desired output in the question, thanks for your help

Comment: Just paste it in the question so people don't have to do the transcription for you.

Comment: @ItayDumay thanks but i think it's not the same, i do not know how can i use that example for my purpose, extracting matrices, i appreciate any hint

Comment: The goal is to have an example that that we can copy / modify and then test by running and comparing with your expected result.

Comment: @tdelaney you are right, i just edited my question, thanks for your help

Comment: Is this just a question about getting a list of pose and 4x4 matrix? I can do that, but I don't know how you want the matrix translation to work. Could the question be narrowed into how to get pose and 4x4 matrix from the file?

Comment: @tdelaney yes it is like that you said if you could give me the output like what I've written it would be a great help for me and I will edit the title as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its easy to determine the start of each group of data (3 integers) you can use `itertools.groupby` break it up for you. This gives you a sub-iterator each time the file changes from 3-things to not-three-things. Whe its 3 things, split out the pose, otherwise let `numpy` build an array from the rest.

```
import itertools
import io
import numpy as np

test = io.StringIO("""0 0 1
1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
-0.00000000 1.00000000 -0.00000000 0.00000000
0.00000000 -0.00000000 1.00000000 0.00000000
0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000
1 1 2
0.99987256 -0.00294761 -0.01569025 -0.00016514
0.00261951 0.99977833 -0.02089080 0.00523247
0.01574835 0.02084704 0.99965864 -0.00371881
0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000
2 2 3
0.99973679 -0.00740811 -0.02171352 0.00091496
0.00681182 0.99960112 -0.02740798 0.01052933
0.02190790 0.02725285 0.99938848 -0.00518150
0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000""")


def get_pose_and_matrix_from_log(fileobj):
    """yield pose, np.array for each group in log file"""
    pose = None
    # each group starts with a 3 integer sequence
    for is_pose_number, data in itertools.groupby(test, 
            lambda line: len(line.strip().split()) == 3):
        if is_pose_number:
            if pose is None:
                raise ValueError("Invalid file format")
            pose = next(data).split(" ", 1)[0]
        else:
            matrix = np.genfromtxt(data)
            yield (pose, matrix)

for pose, matrix in get_pose_and_matrix_from_log(test):
    pass # transform and make json
```

To read from a file, change that loop to

```
with open("\\path\\trajectory.log") as log_file:
    for pose, matrix in get_post_and_matrix_from_log(log_file):
        pass # ... xform
```

Comment: thank you so much,sorry for too much basic questions,i tried to run and print pose and matrix but i got this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log_to_json.py", line 33, in <module>
    for pose, matrix in get_pose_and_matrix_from_log(test):
  File "log_to_json.py", line 27, in get_pose_and_matrix_from_log
    pose = next(data).split(1)[0]
TypeError: must be str or None, not int   , can you tell me how can i solve it?

Comment: Oops - I typed a minor enhancement incorrectly. Fixed.

Comment: thank you so much, one more thing,now i want to open my log file and i used this script :``` with open("\\path\\trajectory.log", "r") as log_file:
    log_string = log_file.read() ```  and i changed test with log_string but i get this error :   File "pose_matrix.py", line 34, in get_pose_and_matrix_from_log
    yield (pose, matrix)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pose' referenced before assignment

Comment: is it the correct script for loading log file? what should i do about the error? thanks

Comment: I updated to show how to read from file. If `pose` is unbound, that means that the 3 integer sequence was not the first line in the file. I added code to detect and raise a ValueError. If your format is different than what is posted, it will need to be accounted for in the code... but since I don't know the _what_, I can't say much about the _how_.